# how to resolve authentication required for my drupal site

Tags: browser, drupal, wamp

I am trying to access my drupal site and an authentication requirement pops up. It asks for a username and password and i don't have any login credentials associated with the site

When i try to cancel it displays a 401 authentication error

Answer (score 0):

It seems your document root is password protected , you can find .htpasswd file your server, may be in your document  root. remove that file also check your .htaccess file and update accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That password protection is not part of the site it self, but provided by apache web server. It's mostly used for protecting staging servers, i.e. from search engines trying to index the pages. Basically in your site root you have ".htaccess" file which defines settings for apache server. Some of those settings are related to password protection and they should look like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

This code defines authentication and "AuthUserFile" parameter defines path to file where your pair of username/password is stored. Password is not plain text but it's encrypted (you have free online tools for encrypting htpasswd passwords).

So, you can see username in that ".htpasswd" file but you can't see the real password and if you want to keep using this protection and can't get the password from other sources you must generate new one to replace old one.

But if you just want to remove this password protection edit .htaccess file and remove this code related to authentication.

You have nice explanation including path to password encryption online service here:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/